# Scraping text injected by Javascript using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the date from a webpage, and the text of the date (after script tag) is injected by JavaScript:
I want to scrape it using Beautifulsoup only, not selenium

```
<div class="row">
    <span class="LName"><a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">[me too]</a></span>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">formatDate('2020,5,23,09,00,00',1)</script>6/23/2020&nbsp;10:00&nbsp;Tuesday
</div>
```

this is the code used to try scraping the date text:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}
r = requests.get(u, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

I try :

```
soup.select('div.row > script')[0].get_text()
```

returns:

```
"formatDate('2020,5,23,09,00,00',1)"
```

and :

```
soup.select('div.row')[0].get_text()
```

returns:

```
"\n[me too] formatDate('2020,5,23,09,00,00',1)\n"
```

when I use Chrome to inspect the tag, I can see the date text after the script tag

when I execute:

```
soup.select('div.row')
```

it returns the tag without the date text

I want to scrape only with Beautifulsoup, not selenium

Comment: You would need a javascript engine which understands the javascript text. But unfortunately Beautiful soup does not do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime


txt = '''<div class="row">
    <span class="LName"><a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">[me too]</a></span>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">formatDate('2020,5,23,09,00,00',1)</script>6/23/2020&nbsp;10:00&nbsp;Tuesday
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')
year, month, day, hour, minutes, sec, *_ = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', soup.select_one('div.row > script').contents[0]))
d = datetime(year=year, month=month + 1, day=day, hour=hour + 1, minute=minutes, second=sec)
print(datetime.strftime(d, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %A'))
```

Prints:

```
06/23/2020 10:00 Tuesday
```

Comment: it return an error: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
after I run datetime(year=year, month=month + 1, day=day, hour=hour + 1, minute=minutes, second=sec)

Comment: @Ravanelli You must do `from datetime import datetime`, not just `import datetime` <-- that's [module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that BS does not render Javascript at all.  I use Selenium to grab the content, and then BS to parse.  If you insist on not using selenium, there are other packages that will render the page first, then you feed it into BeautifulSoup for parsing.

Try: https://github.com/makinacorpus/spynner
PhantomJS

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on the date to always be generated with the `formatDate()` function and can assume the date display format, then you could extract the call with BeautifulSoup as you do and then use regular expressions to parse it out:

```
import re
date_call = soup.select('div.row > script')[0].get_text()
year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds, dow = re.search(r"formatDate\('(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)',(\d)\)", date_call).groups()
```

The variables will then give you the components you need to reconstruct the date:

```
dow_map = {str(i):dow for i, dow in enumerate(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday'])}
date_text = f'{month}/{day}/{year} {h}:{m} {dow_map[dow]}'
```

Comment: the issue is that date from the call is always behind by one month and one hour

Comment: If it's always the case, then you can just use month+1 and hour+1 in your date_text assignment.